Should vertical communication / decision making between employees be allowed?
Consider a typical hierarchical structure:

A is the manager of B and C, while B is the manager of D, E and F, and so on.
Horizontal communication between employees is marked in the red dotted line: L directly contacts J.
Vertical communication is marked in the green dashed line. It requires that employees cannot contact each other directly, but only their direct managers and subordinates. All communication must, therefore, go through the lowest manager that is above all employees who wish to communicate.
Examples.

L, to proceed, needs knowledge only J has. L therefore asks J for this knowledge. J shares their knowledge with L. (horizontal communication)

L reports to H that they must obtain some information to proceed. H requests that information from E, who requests that information from B. B instructs F to share the relevant information, who in turn instructs J to share that information. Now both L and J are instructed by their immediate managers to communicate and J, in particular, is instructed to share some specific information, so now J and L can communicate directly insofar as this is required for J to share the information they were instructed to share. (vertical decision making)

L the implementer reports a bug that some field is marked as required, even though there is no relevant data that can be entered in that field. J the programmer was assigned to handle that bug. J sees in source code that the data from that field is not actually required for the business process to continue and it seems correct to leave that field empty, particularly when there is no relevant data to enter there. It is thus concluded that the field is incorrectly marked as required and the mark is removed. (horizontal decision making)

J is disciplined for their unauthorized decision making. A programmers' job is to implement business requirements, not to decide on them. L likewise receives a warning, for an implementer's job is to instruct the client on how to use the product and not to decide on how the product itself should work. If L and J believe that the field should not be marked as required, they should report their opinion to their respective managers and in the end it will be B's job to make the final decision on whether the field should continue being marked as required and if yes, then what data should be entered there. A bug happens when the program behaves in a way contrary to business requirements and therefore being assigned to the bug only gives J the license to modify code as required to make the application conform to these requirements. If, however, there is a confusion on what the business requirements really are or it appears that perhaps it is the specification that is wrong, then J must only limit themselves to a preliminary analysis that states that fact and assign the bug back to their manager. That decision might even be to defer the actual decision to L and J, but only if and when B makes this decision then L and J may proceed. (Vertical decision making)


I have seen both models being argued for by competent people.
Arguments for requiring the vertical model:

Managers decide what an employee should be doing at any given time. It is not acceptable for an employee to be distracted from the task they are assigned to by another employee.
Good security practices dictate that each employee should only know what they strictly require to know to do the job that is assigned to them. Employees shouldn't, therefore, be allowed to share information between various teams without supervision.
Managers decide on the shape of the product. To do so managers must know what is being done. Managers cannot meaningfully shape the product according to their vision and data if employees decide for themselves what to do.
If employees are allowed to self-organize, then it may happen that L and J set to do something that K and I are already doing or, even worse, L and J may start doing something directly opposite to what K and I are alraedy implementing. This results in double and triple work and therefore inefficiency.

Arguments for allowing horizontal communication / decision making:

Umm... Unfortunately, I heard them many years ago and I don't really remember them, sorry :(
Micromanagement overloads managers and kills employees' creativity and sense of responsibility of the final product
In many cases of 'horizontal' decision making the situation is rather obvious and trivial
Bothering managers with all trivial cases is a sign of employees' lack of self-reliance
Going all the way up the hierarchy chain and then down again is time consuming and therefore inefficient, allowing direct communication / decision making between employees may make the job done much faster
Management works best if managers limit themselves to inspiring and leading the team, rather than attempt to essentially do the technical peoples' job
Technical people (the ones who do the actual job) might actually know best what to do in the case of details, managers should rather know the big picture and be able to step in when conflicts arise
Again, I'm sure I misrepresented arguments for the horizontal model since I've heard them a long time ago

Should it be allowed for employees to communicate directly, skipping the 'lowest common manager' route? Or even make deicisions in this way, especially if the case seems detailed and rather obvious? Or should it, rather, be absolutely required that going through the 'lowest common manager' route must be mandatory in all cases?

There is no way to prevent people from doing what makes sense. Communicating directly makes sense. So does informing your manager of any decisions made that way. I don't see anything that needs to be addressed at a systematic level here.

You're looking for a generic answer. There is no generic answer. Companies of different sizes are going to behave differently. Companies in different countries/cultures are going to behave differently. Also, companies in different sectors are going to behave differently. For instance, a company with a well established technology stack is going to behave very differently from a company that is required to invent technology from scratch.

This sounds like a horrible place to work.

Neither extreme is remotely practical.
If everyone in IT reports up through the CIO and everyone in finance reports up through the CFO, requiring all communication to be strictly vertical would mean that any time someone in finance wanted a new report and every time someone in IT needed to meet someone with business knowledge to clarify a requirement, those requests would require the CEO to weigh in.  No CEO of an organization with at least 5 levels of hierarchy could possibly even read the volume of trivial emails that would be produced let alone meaningfully manage them.
If communication was strictly horizontal, it would be virtually impossible to manage the organization.  No one would know what their subordinates were doing, no one would be able to reprioritize tasks or start new initiatives.
Practically, the only sensible approach is to do both.  Managers create systems that facilitate communication between areas of the organization that don't require decisions to flow all the way up to the CEO.  A finance user can call the help desk and get someone from IT to come fix their broken Excel install without anyone's manager needing to approve.  Different systems might be in place for that same user to request a new report or to request changes to a screen in an internal system they use.  Those systems might require some level of managerial involvement to authorize or to prioritize-- new reports may simply end up in a FIFO queue for the reporting team to pick up, system changes might go to a higher level of management for approval and prioritization.  Those systems will have the ability to provide higher-level managers with the information they need to manage-- the number of trouble tickets submitted and average resolution time are important for the manager of the help desk to figure out staffing needs for example.
Individual workers need to reach out to people outside their reporting structure to do their jobs but need to ensure that their managers are appropriately aware of those conversations.  Different managers and employees will have different amounts of autonomy and different issues require different sorts of communication.  In your example, if L and J spend half an hour in a meeting to discuss the field and conclude that it isn't needed, that information almost certainly ought to get communicated to their respective managers and/or to the project manager that manages the requirements.  Depending on the importance, those managers may choose to raise the issue higher up the organizational structure.

It's impossible to answer the question in the abstract because it depends on how the organisation is working overall and which staff perform which functions.
You seem to have a pretty good grasp of the factors potentially in play.
Despite the intelligent enumeration of all those factors, you don't seem to have considered that either the factors might apply differently to different organisations, or that they may apply differently to different situations in the same organisation.
Moreover, it is possible for an organisation to be organised dysfunctionally, in which there are objective reasons in the context why all simple communications must go via an extremely circuitous route of higher managers, but this could be solved by organising the various roles differently.

"Good security practices dictate that each employee should only know what they strictly require to know to do the job that is assigned to them. Employees shouldn't, therefore, be allowed to share information between various teams without supervision."
This is questionable actually.
Restricting information sharing can limit the risk of malicious or negligent divulging of confidential information.
However, having limited knowledge about what information is confidential in the first place, and why it is confidential, actually raises the risk of confidential information being divulged accidentally or because someone gets social engineered by an actually malicious actor significantly.

It is only a problem when it becomes a problem
So, this is going to be a sort of Frame Challenge answer.
If the company has competent people, who are communicating efficiently, then having a more informal approach to communication lines is all well and good.
The Employees are getting on with the work, the Managers are getting on with managing.
You often see this in more start-up-ish companies whereby there is a flatter hierarchy and no defined reporting routes yet - everyone is just kind of getting on with it.
Where this becomes an issue is when you have one of the following:

An individual or team becomes the go-to area for difficult or specialist work pieces and they have more work coming in than they can complete (a bottleneck)

Management looses visibility of what is happening, which invariably means when a ball is dropped (it will be...) that this reflects badly


I could go on, but I think you get the picture.
From my perspective (as a card carrying libertarian) - restrictions on the flow of information always restricts both creativity and efficiency.
Sometimes those are trade-offs that have to be made (for example - Trade Secrets and IP) - and so the line should be drawn as thin as necessary.
The thinness of that line depends on various factors - but most of which come down to the employees and management themselves. If they can work efficiently and collectively prioritise and the work is getting done - then freeing up the communication channels is the way to go.
If there is departmental in-fighting or overloading or other negative outcomes then a bit more structure may be needed.
